# Changing the vertical alignment of `multlined` from the mathtools package

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, amsmath, align, mathtools

[Package `mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides the vertical alignments `t`op, `c`enter, and `b`ottom:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempdimc}{\the\textwidth}
\settowidth{\@tempdima}{\hspace{2em}(\ref{equationA})}
\addtolength{\@tempdimc}{-\the\@tempdima}
\edef\somelength{\the\@tempdimc}
\makeatother

\begin{align}
  & \framebox[0.8\linewidth]{\strut} \\
= & \!%
\begin{multlined}[t][\somelength]
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} \\
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} 
\end{multlined}                     \label{equationA} \\
= & \!%
\begin{multlined}[c][\somelength]
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} \\
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} 
\end{multlined}                     \label{equationB} \\
= & \!%
\begin{multlined}[b][\somelength]
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} \\
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} 
\end{multlined}                     \label{equationC} \\
= & \framebox[0.8\linewidth]{\strut} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: current result of MWE]

What I would like to get is top alignment regarding "=" and bottom alignment regarding the "`\label`" (number 2 in the following example):

[image: wanted result]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Small comment: It isn't necessary to load `amsmath` explicitly; it is already loaded by `mathtools`.

Comment: You cannot with `multlined`, it only handles contents, not where the equation number is placed in relation to that content (that is handled by the outer env, here `align`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not try something like this, "hiding" the width of the first line and
putting the equals signs after the `&`, and, in the case of the `multline`
components, within the scope of `multline`?

[image]

the input:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \rlap{\framebox[0.8\linewidth]{\strut}}\quad \\
 &\begin{multlined}[b][.8\textwidth]
  = \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} \\
  \framebox[0.55\linewidth]{\strut} 
\end{multlined}                     \label{equationA} \\
 &= \framebox[0.8\linewidth]{\strut} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Stephen -- i must admit, i find that aligning the beginning of the line that precedes the first equals sign in a displayed equation to be counter-intuitive.  it isn't the style recommended in swanson's "[mathematics into type](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf)" (section 3.35), which is how i was trained.

Comment: Well, yes, `\framebox[0.1\linewidth]{\strut}` & \rlap{$ {} = \framebox[0.7\linewidth]{\strut} $}` proved to be the better solution. Thanks for the hint! Before `\begin{multlined}` a `\!` is necessary to counter an intern `\,` in `multlined`.